# Continuous change in state freezes the app React-Native

Tags: react-native, progress-bar

I am trying to show the progress of a downloading file in a ProgressBar of `@react-native-community/progress-bar-android`. As the progress changes in `state` continuously, it freezes the application. Assume I want to cancel the download by pressing a button, it doesn't work. Other components are not functioning as the progressbar state value changes in a loop. The progress in the ProgressBar is working fine. But the other components are not functioning till the process finishes. Is there any way I can try Threads here?

Comment: You can make it better in performance by separate the progress update component and make it PureComponent and pass update value as prop

Comment: Most likely you are blocking the JS thread by running so many re-renders hence touch events are not working. Open perf monitor from dev menu(shake device) & check the frame-rate. If the frame-rate is stuck on something like -2, you need to optimise your components. The change in progress state is causing re-renders in other components too, not just the progress bar.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'll give it a try and tell you...

Comment: I tried to show the downloading progress in a separated component, still the issue was there. As I was using  ```react-native-fs``` to download the file, I set ```progressDivider: 6``` for the configs of that and it is ok now. Thank you guys. But looking forward try both of your suggestions later